# Kentico Tag output but not links

Tags: kentico

With help from Branded, i have tag working. At this point, we don't need tags to link, so i have tags being displayed like this (in an ascx transformation):

```html
<p class='date'><%# IfEmpty(Eval("DocumentTags"),"",Eval("DocumentTags").ToString() + " | ") %><%# FormatDateTime(Eval("Date"),"MMM d, yyyy") %></p>
```

This works, but i get the tags wrapped in double quotes. I'm traying TrimEnd, or LastIndexOf, but just getting errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the method `Replace()` on the double quotes.  Something like `Eval<string>("DocumentTags").Replace("\"", "")` should work.

Comment: that gives me this error: [TempITemplate.Template]: http://server/CMSVirtualFiles/Transformations/=vg=f5055ab6-e2c3-46a5-b98b-d8e1531b2bc7/kff.LatestArticles/ArticlesListing.ascx(13): error CS1011: Empty character literal. I'm going to keep digging.

Comment: Sorry had the wrong syntax in the Replace() method.  Try what I updated the answer with now.

Comment: Ok, i see what you did, escape the double quote. I was down the rabit home of SubString :)